# Firefox drawImage tot canvas error: IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, drawimage

I used to work with Chrome, but I needed to test my plugin with Firefox. 
I'm trying to capture the video element and draw it to the canvas. In Chrome everything works fine, but in Firefox I get this annoying error which I can't fix yet.

```
IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
```

I'm using the following line of code to draw to video `$("#video")[0]` to the canvas `$("#output")[0].getContext('2d')`:

```
outputCtx.drawImage(video, 0,0, video.width, video.height, 0, 0, 1815, 1358);
```

I'll get the error on the video.width and video.height values. 
I've made a JSFiddle which works fine in Chrome but gives the error in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/ronnyrr/KD2bu/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use these properties instead:

```
outputCtx.drawImage(video, 0,0, video.videoWidth, video.videoWeight,
                    0, 0, 1815, 1358);
```

The source rectangle must always be within the source bitmap. The error message occurs when one of the parameters are outside or 0 or negative.

In Firefox it may be that width does not reflect the actual video size. Therefor try the videoWidth/Height properties or in worst case combine them:

```
outputCtx.drawImage(video, 0,0,
                    video.videoWidth||video.width,
                    video.videoHeight||video.height,
                    0, 0, 1815, 1358);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've changed your suggestion (http://jsfiddle.net/ronnyrr/KD2bu/1/) and now I'm not getting the error anymore. The snapshot is taken, but for some reason the dimensions are way to large (even the width and height attributes on the video element are correct) in both browsers (Chrome and FF) ..